# props keep showing as $attrs in VUE DEV TOOLS

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuejs3, vuejs-transition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C6vt.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyAp1.png) My props keep showing as $attrs in VUE DEV TOOLS
I have tried disabling attrs using inheritAttrs: false and v-bind="$attrs",does not work

```
// props 
:showLoadMoreButton="load"

  data() {
    return {
      load: true
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

If something is appearing as an attribute, it means it's not registered as a prop on the component.

Try registering your unwanted attribute as a prop:

```
// props 
:showLoadMoreButton="load"

export default {
  props: {
    showLoadMoreButton: Boolean
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. In my case the error was that i didnt close the script tag in the component